# Using Oauth token to get Google analytics in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, oauth, dotnetopenauth, gdata

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get Google Analytics data using OAuth?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5005665/how-to-get-google-analytics-data-using-oauth)

I'm struggling with it already for 2 days and can't make it work.
I need to get access to Google analytics using Oauth.

I'm using `DotNetOpenAuth` to login to google using Oauth (I can login and get contact list - sample solution from `DotNetOpenAuth`)

Now I'm trying to get analytics using `Google.Gdata` and I can get it using ClientLogin (providing user email and password).

Now I trying to use login token obtained using `DotNetOpenAuth` to get analytics but can't make it work. Indeed token obtained using ClientLogin differs from token obtained using `DotNetOpenAuth`.

Can anyone help with it?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for help folks.

See my answer here [How to get Google Analytics data using OAuth?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5005665/how-to-get-google-analytics-data-using-oauth-authsub/5153097#5153097)